# React Native firebase realtime database pagination with startAt

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

I have a realtime DB and I want to implement pagination for my FlatList. When the component mounts to display 10 recipes from db and after the user reach the end, to fetch 10 more and append to the existing list and so on.

For some reason when I reach the end and 10 more recipes are fetching it encounters duplicates.

```
export const fetchRecipes = async (startAfter: string | null): Promise<FetchRecipesResult> => {
  try {
    let recipesSnapshot: FirebaseDatabaseTypes.DataSnapshot;
    let recipesQuery = database().ref('/pathToRecipes/').orderByKey();
    if (startAfter) {
      recipesQuery = recipesQuery.startAt(startAfter).limitToFirst(10); 
    } else {
      recipesQuery = recipesQuery.limitToFirst(10); 
    }

    recipesSnapshot = await recipesQuery.once('value');

    const recipesVal = recipesSnapshot.val();
    let nextStartAfter = "";
    const recipeIds = Object.keys(recipesVal);
    if (recipeIds.length > 0) {
      nextStartAfter = recipeIds[0];
    }

    const allergenSnapshot = await database().ref('pathToAllergens').once('value');
    const allergenData = allergenSnapshot.val();

    let recipes = recipesVal;

    // Fetch recipeStats and allergen information for each recipe and combine it with the recipe data
    const recipePromises = Object.keys(recipes).map(async recipeId => {
   
      const recipeStatsSnapshot = await database().ref(`/pathToRecipeStats/${recipeId}`).once('value');
      const recipeStats = recipeStatsSnapshot.val();

      let allergens = [];

      if (recipes[recipeId].allergens) {
        allergens = Object.keys(recipes[recipeId].allergens).map(allergenId => {
          return {
            allergenId: allergenId,
            ...allergenData[allergenId],
          };
        });
      }
      return {
        ...recipes[recipeId],
        recipeId,
        recipeStats,
        allergens,
      };
    });

    const recipesWithInfo = await Promise.all(recipePromises) || [];
    return {recipesWithInfo, nextStartAfter};
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error + "here");
    return { recipesWithInfo: [], nextStartAfter: "" };
  }
};
```

```
  const getRecipes = async () => {
    try {
      const { recipesWithInfo, nextStartAfter } = await fetchRecipes(startAfter);
      if (recipesWithInfo.length > 0) {
        setRecipesShown(prevRecipes => [...prevRecipes, ...recipesWithInfo]);
        setStartAfter(nextStartAfter);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

```
 <FlatList
      data={recipesShown}
      keyExtractor={item => item.recipeId}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <View style={tw`mt-2`}>
          <RecipeInfoItem />
        </View>
      )}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
      onEndReached={getRecipes}
```

Not to mention that for some reason the recipes fetched are in reverse order compared to db that's why I'm using nextStartAfter = recipeIds[0] instead of nextStartAfter = recipeIds[recipeIds.length-1] to get the last element.
In Db is 'recipe1, recipe2, recipe3' and fetched it returns 'recipe1, recipe2, recipe3'.

I already tried multiple approaches, but none worked.